# Access a private web server using static IP from Android Application

Tags: networking

I want to access an Oracle web service in my Android application. But the web service is on my company's server so the public cannot access it. But our Android app is going to be used by the public. Is there a way to use that web service and connect to the server without changing the server's security configurations..? Thank you very much.

Comment: That's a networking question, not a programming question. The answer is "No" -- unless you breach security, you can not circumvent a firewall. Talk to your network admin about this.

Comment: how about writing some proxy before your company servers? that proxy server takes the request and talks to your company server and returns back with info.

Answer (score -1):

you can either try tunneling through a web server as is a standard industry practice. Setup a pair of web server in front of oracle app servers and then a load balancer if front of webs servers. The firewall can be configured to allow traffic on ports 80 (standard http port) or 443 (standard https port). Everything below the load balancer stays protected inside the firewall and you wont have to tweak your oracle server for security configuration changes.